# Software for computing Thurston's unit ball

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, homology, mathematical-software, computational-topology

Is there any software which can be used for computing Thurston's unit ball (for second homology of 3-manifolds) of link complements? In particular can I do that with SnapPy?

PS: even a table for Thurston's ball of two component links would be helpful for me.

Comment: In principle, the Thurston norm may be computed from Heegaard Floer homology. There are some packages to do this sort of thing, but I have no idea how to use them, or whether they could be modified to compute Thurston norm efficiently. See e.g. http://www.math.columbia.edu/~lipshitz/research.html#Programming

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Better late than never."  Stephan Tillmann and William Worden have produced the software package **tnorm**.  This can be found here:

https://pypi.org/project/tnorm/

The software should be able to deal with hyperbolic two-component links easily. William replies to emails, as well.  :)

Answer (score 8):

I am not aware of any implementation. The best known algorithm is [Cooper and Tillmann's](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0673), the closest (which is not very) to a table is in [Curt McMullen's classical paper.](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/papers/home/text/papers/alex/alex.pdf)